# Automate Teams notification with visuals with Power BI Alert is triggered

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-teams

Thank you for the time of checking this out.

My goal is to have Power Automate send my customer a teams notification when a goal in a metric changes, but not only with the values, but also with a / the visual linked to the goal.

I have already managed to make an automation in Power Automate that does the following:
When Goal changes --> Get a Goal --> Post message to Chat or Channel.

This produces a text notification with the content I want in it, but to make it look a bit nicer, and more in context, I would like to add a viual.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm if this is what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-automate-visual?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it. Sadly, no. The way I understand what you refferenced, a user would have to click the button to trigger the Power Automation. What I would like is when a goal (in Metrics) changes / changes status, the correlating visual gets fetched, and then sent to teams or though an e-mail.

Comment: You can use the Export to File for Power BI Reports action to automatically distribute a Power BI report via email. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export  But sending notifications with visual doesn't seem to be feasible.

Comment: All right, I see. I have been playing with that option today, but this seems to be a feature limited to Premium users. As a Pro user, this seems out of reach for now. Or might you know a workaround?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other way.